# Recorded video as live using php

Tags: php, live-streaming, broadcasting

I need to broadcast means
Everyone will view the video as it played, not at the beginning of the video once they visited the web page.

I saw some code like this for embedding video,

```
<object width="425px" height="360px" >
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"/>
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>
    <param name="movie" value="http://mediaservices.myspace.com/services/media/embed.aspx/m=5385825,t=1,mt=video,searchID=,primarycolor=,secondarycolor="/>
    <embed src="http://mediaservices.myspace.com/services/media/embed.aspx/m=5385825,t=1,mt=video,searchID=,primarycolor=,secondarycolor=" width="425" height="360" allowFullScreen="true" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent"/>
</object>
```

i need to know is it possible with PHP , Search several times in web, but did nnt get a proper solution yet.

Comment: And what is the exact question?

Comment: @Rune "How to setup video streaming with PHP?"

Comment: if its not possible with PHP then how can i do that , in my php driven website

Comment: I misunderstood the question. You want to know how to allow users to "tune in" to a webcast already in progress and see it "live" (like how NBC does the Olympics), right?

Comment: Everyone just slow down, it's not possible to be done client side, because SOMETHING has to serve the video. It's so you can't just download the whole thing and then just seek to where everyone else is.

Comment: i need to add play a video in my website, i can manage it from the back end. But now when a user access the page the video play from the beginning point.. i just need to make it as working like a live TV script

Comment: Does [this link](http://gonzalo123.wordpress.com/2010/09/20/live-video-streaming-with-php/) help?

Comment: Matt certainly seems closer than anyone so far.

Comment: Are you recording this live or is it pre-recorded?

Answer (score -1):

This is not about the clientside code. You should configure a single stream in your video hosting platform. That's where the challenge is being fixed, not in the client side code.

To be more specific:

> I need to broadcast

As far as I see from some server, I don't see anything about a client side cam.

> means Everyone will view the video as it played

So it is a stream send to all visitors of the page, not personal chat stream just like a TV broadcasting.

> , not at the beginning of the video once they visited the web page.

So you start it centrally and you can hook in. So if the stream is at 35 minutes and you start watching you miss it. Just like TV.

If that is all correct then you should configure that at the server. So don't stream separately for every viewer but just use a general stream.

Comment: Clearly, he's asking if it's possible in php, not javascript.

Comment: I don't know what but your comment says the same as I did: "This cannot be done client side". I am not talking about javascript anywhere, the client is not directly relevant to the question. The stream is the part where it should be configured and nowhere else.

Comment: I didn't realize that people were commenting about javascript. That being said I'm holding my -1 because you're answering the comment not the question.

Comment: so you mean .. for doing this i need to add my video files normally using the above code and need to make changes only in server right?

Comment: i saw one post related to my question , http://forums.adobe.com/thread/581919#2608791, but its using FMS.. i want to do the same using php

Comment: The problem with that AGK is that you don't have any 'video files' because you're streaming. The code you posted unfortunately isn't tremendously useful to you because they're using ASP.NET to slice up the video to provide to the user.

Comment: for the user its just like a live streaming.. but i tried to broadcast the recorded video files through my website, my doubt is , each time the user open the webpage how can i set the starting point of the video same as the running point in server..

Comment: Matts comment is very helpful, read that article and it might give you a better picture at the problem you're looking at.

Comment: in server side that video playing continuously , if one client open the webpage his video's starting point is same as the point which is in the server's current playing point

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14810/discussion-between-agk-and-voronoipotato)